# Application visibility on google play for app with camera permission

Tags: android

Welcome,

I'm trying figure out why my app is not visible for example for samsung galaxy mini 2. This is my configuration

```
Features 7 features
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN

Required permissions 8 permissions
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.android.vending.BILLING
```

I found that this may be the solution but I'm not sure

I will check it but still I want to understand how it works.

Is there any page which based on permissions can tell why specific device is not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting `android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS`.

The Galaxy Mini 2 review [here](http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-mini-2-review-50007045/) says;

> The camera on the back is only 3 megapixels and *there's no auto-focus*.